# Manually creating a circuit-breaker-wrapped feign client

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I'm trying to manually create a circuit-breaker-wrapped Feign client, so that I can use callbacks.
I understand that there's another approach that kind of simplify this, which is using the `@FeignClient` annotation, as well as enabling fallbacks with `feign.circuitbreaker.enabled=true` and importing the `spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j` dependency. Unfortunately this does not solve our problem, we need to manually create them (with code).

Below is how I'm creating a simple Feign client:

```
@Bean
public SomeClient client() {
    Request.Options options = new Request.Options(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 3000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, false);

    return Feign.builder()
            .options(options)
            .contract(new SpringMvcContract())
            .target(SomeClient.class, "some_url");
}
```

Looking at the Spring's `FeignClientsConfiguration` class, I found the piece of code responsible of enabling the circuit breaker, which is:

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@ConditionalOnClass({ CircuitBreaker.class })
@ConditionalOnProperty({ "feign.circuitbreaker.enabled" })
protected static class CircuitBreakerPresentFeignBuilderConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean({ Builder.class, CircuitBreakerFactory.class })
    public Builder defaultFeignBuilder(Retryer retryer) {
        return Feign.builder().retryer(retryer);
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    @ConditionalOnBean({ CircuitBreakerFactory.class })
    public Builder circuitBreakerFeignBuilder() {
        return FeignCircuitBreaker.builder();
    }
    
}
```

After that, I tried changing from `Feign.builder()` to `FeignCircuitBreaker.builder()` within our `client` bean method, as it supports the `T target(Target<T> target, T fallback)` method, although no luck on that: some weird null pointer exception at `org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignCircuitBreakerInvocationHandler.invoke(FeignCircuitBreakerInvocationHandler.java:88)`.

Looking at the `FeignClientsConfiguration` class again, the `circuitBreakerFeignBuilder` method depends on the `CircuitBreakerFactory` bean, which is supposedly not being created automatically, so I tried creating one, but this just gets things even more complicated.

I couldn't find much information regarding this issue on the internet, hopefully someone knows how to solve this.